Copilot in Visual Studio problem with inline shortcut
I'm using Copilot in VS 17.11.3.
Everything works as expected except the shortcut for invoking inline chat Alt + /. By default, my keyboard is not set to English, and the / character can only be inputted using either Shift + 7 or the num pad on my keyboard.
Neither the Alt + Shift + 7 nor Alt + Num_Pad_/ works for invoking chat.
However, if I switch my keyboard layout to English, the shortcut functions as expected (in this case / character being next to the Right Shift).
Is there any way to handle this on a non-English keyboard? Because switching the language every time I want to invoke inline chat isn't a viable long-term solution.
